# Adding signed and unsigned integers

Tags: c++

I want to add a signed int to an unsigned int:

```
int num1=20; //Signed
unsigned  num2=-10; //Unsigned
printf("%u",num1+num2);
```

My understanding:

When we add signed (int, long, long long) to unsigned of the same rank, then unsigned always gets the highest preference. So, the num2 will be changed to *4294967286* and num1 will remain 20 after unsigned conversion. And the addition should be *4294967306.* But the answer is 10.

I think this is a bad way of coding as it creates confusion. But still, I would like to understand where I'm getting wrong.

Comment: Why do you expect a result greater than 2^32 in 32 bit integer arithmetic?

Comment: This *may* be useful: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages, especially when it comes to semantics. Please pick *one* language.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Oops!! You're right. It's a stupid question. I should have checked that. Thanks

Comment: 4294967306 causes an unsigned overflow.

Comment: @FeiXiang Unsigned integer math does not overflow. It wraps.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Is there any reference link to have a better understanding of the difference between overflow and wraps? Or why it should wrap?

Comment: @DebasishRayMohapatra http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: @BaummitAugen That's what I meant. I thought unsigned overflow *is* wrapping around, thanks for correcting my terminology.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `num2` will represent the number `4294967286 = 2^32 - 10`. when you add `20` to that number you will get

```
num2 + 20 = 2^32 - 10 + 20 = 2^32 + 10 = 10
```

The last step is due to an overflow since your variable is stored in a 32 bit data type. For further reading

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow